# How to overlay a horizontal bar chart with dots in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I know how to overlay a vertical bar chart with dots, by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Types':['A','B','C'],
                   'Val1':[-10,-15,-5],
                   'Val2':[-6,-8,-2]})
df=df.set_index('Types')
ax = df['Val1'].plot.bar(figsize=(10,7))
df['Val2'].plot(style='o',color=[1,0.8,0])
```

which works nicely. But how do I produce this graph, but with horizontal bars and corresponding dots? If I change the line above and use `barh` then the bars flip as I want, but superimposing the dots no longer works. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal bar graphs can be realized with `df.plot.barh`, but overlaid scatterplots are controlled using Zorder.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Types':['A','B','C'],
                   'Val1':[-10,-15,-5],
                   'Val2':[-6,-8,-2]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot.barh(y='Val1', figsize=(10,7), ax=ax, zorder=1)
ax.scatter(df['Val2'].tolist(), [0,1,2], color=[1,0.8,0], zorder=2, label='Val2')
ax.legend()
ax.set_yticklabels(df['Types'])
plt.show()
```

[image]